# how to have css affect other divs in the same container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have one list affect another list... I have made an example fiddle to try to get this figured out.. I am just stuck!

Basically I have a list of items and a list of images.
I would like to have a different image display as each item is highlighted.
Here is my fiddle mock-up:  http://jsfiddle.net/t9hznk0w/

Basically Container is the main div... then there is the list of items and then another place-holder list for the images.  In this example I am simply trying to proof of concept (I will later do it by changing the opacity) but I cannot seem to get the first list items to affect the second list items when hovered.
In my example I am simply trying to change the color and bold the second element.

Please any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="container1">
        <li class="itm1">Item 1</li>
        <li class="itm2">Item 2</li>
        <li class="itm3">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="container2">
        <li class="img1">ITEM 1 IMAGE</li>
        <li class="img2">ITEM 2 IMAGE</li>
        <li class="img3">ITEM 3 IMAGE</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.itm1:hover ~ .img1 {
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
}
.img1:hover {
color: green;
}
.itm1:hover {
color: yellow;
}
```

I have tried + > ~ and various combinations
still no success... please help!

Comment: Try applying the CSS to the parent div. `#container:hover #container1 { color: green; } #container:hover #container2 { color: yellow }` or something.

Comment: Can we not just use javascript?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it with only CSS if those elements are not siblings or descendants..

Comment: The closest you can get is http://jsfiddle.net/t9hznk0w/6/ like Tyler mentioned, if you want this to happen on the 'li' level then use js, can't do it with only css

Comment: As jimore009 mentioned, you can't do this with CSS because it has no parent selector. If the item you were trying to affect was a child for the list item then you can do something like thing
`.itm1:hover .childeItem{ color: blue }`

Comment: If you only want to use HTML and CSS, you can change the HTML and make the elements siblings, at least. Then you can apply CSS to those elements. Is this an option for you, changing the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you requested only HTML and CSS, I changed the markup in order to obtain what you intend. The lack of parent selector in CSS turn your request impossible for that markup.

```css
.itm1:hover ~ .img1 {
    color: red;
}
.itm2:hover ~ .img2 {
    color: red;
}
.itm3:hover ~ .img3 {
    color: red;
}
.img1:hover {
    color: green;
}
#container ul li:hover {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul id="container1">
        <li class="itm1">Item 1</li>
        <li class="itm2">Item 2</li>
        <li class="itm3">Item 3</li>
        <br/>
        <li class="img1 container2">THIS IS ITEM 1</li>
        <li class="img2 container2">THIS IS ITEM 2</li>
        <li class="img3 container2">THIS IS ITEM 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is a HTML and CSS only solution, not sure it fits into your requirements.

## **Fiddle**

Answer (score 4):

This can not be done because the two elements you are trying to target are neither siblings nor descendants and there is no parent selector in CSS to traverse the DOM. You can do this relatively easily in JS using `.index()`

```
$("ul#container1").find("li").hover(function(){
   var index = $(this).index(); //index position of hovered li
   $("#container2").find("li").eq(index).toggleClass("active"); //find same position in other ul
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t9hznk0w/7/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to hide and show item elements via the filter option. While hiding items that do not match the selected item will be hidden. Isotope would be the best solution http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html. I would go with the fitRows option because it is ideal for items that have the same height. And the animation is supper cool and smooth.

For the best step by step help with the install check out http://bootstrapwp.com/?ref=14